# Magento 2, Can we import 10K product of csv at once

Tags: magento2, importexport

I have a client who wants to import the 10k product at once, He is saying that he has done it earlier, but I don't think it is possible, I have never seen that much of products to get imported at once.

So, please help me and suggest, how can I make it possible by any means necessary.
Any suggestions will also be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: Please you one time try  import product and which error showing..

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project once where we had to import around 18k products, using the CSV approach.

We found it too unpredictable/unstable to import them all in one go, so split the file into batches of 5,000 products. This made it easier to manage, and each one processed in full (rather than the frontend hanging and having to rely on monitoring the backend process).

Comment: Thanks Geat, for the reply,